# Does `return result` in this code affect on the result of this decorator?

Tags: python, return, decorator

I come across a tutorial about `decorators` today, but I couldn't figure out, what is the point of `return result` in code below. Since, its existence and deleting it won't affect anything with the output of the code.

```
def timer_decorator(original_func):
    def wrapper_func(*args, **kwargs):
        import time 
        t1 = time.time()
        time.sleep(2)
        result = original_func(*args, **kwargs)
        t2 = time.time()
        res = t2 - t1
        print('Ran {} in {} secs.'.format(original_func.__name__, res))
        return result   # here
    return wrapper_func


@timer_decorator
def display_info(name, age, email):
    print('Display info for {}, {} years old [{}]'.format(name, age, email))      


display_info('Marry Doe', 25, 'marry_doe@gmail.com')
```

either if I erase `return result` or let it be the output in either case would be the same. Please tell me if I am missing something. Thank you

edit: I edited `display_info` function and this time it returns something:

```
@timer_decorator
def display_info(name, age, email):
    return 'Display info for {}, {} years old [{}]'.format(name, age, email)
```

again, this is the result if i delete `return result` or just let it be there:

```
Ran display_info in 2.0001468658447266 secs.
```

no changes

Comment: What if the function you decorate returns something?

Comment: `Since, its existence and deleting it won't affect anything with the output of the code` that's because your `display_info` function doesn't return anything, (or None)

Comment: I edited `display_info` to return something, again its existence and non existence doesn't effect the answer. please elaborate further

Comment: Your function works by explicitly printing inside of it. So, returning anything won't change that `print` execution. For a test just return something from the display function and catch that in your call to the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ponder this, if you return a number from your display_info you can assign it to x but if you remove the return result you will get None instead.

```py
def timer_decorator(original_func):
    def wrapper_func(*args, **kwargs):
        import time 
        t1 = time.time()
        time.sleep(2)
        result = original_func(*args, **kwargs)
        t2 = time.time()
        res = t2 - t1
        print('Ran {} in {} secs.'.format(original_func.__name__, res))
        return result   # here
    return wrapper_func


@timer_decorator
def display_info(name, age, email):
    print('Display info for {}, {} years old [{}]'.format(name, age, email))
    return 10


x = display_info('Marry Doe', 25, 'marry_doe@gmail.com')
print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's understand with below example -

1. ***Decorator inner function which returning something :***

```
import time
def calculate_time_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('Before Time {}!'.format(time.time()))
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print('After Time {}!'.format(time.time()))
        return ret
    return wrapper
```

Here, our `func()` is `get_square()` which is returning square value. So, we are expecting this squared value to be returned in `ret`

```
@calculate_time_decorator
def get_square(n):
    print("given number is:", n)
    return n * n
```

2. ***Decorator inner function which returning nothing:***

```
import time
def calculate_time_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('Before Time {}!'.format(time.time()))
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print('After Time {}!'.format(time.time()))
        return ret
    return wrapper
```

Here, our `func()` is `myfunc()` which is not returning any value(since it's only printing `Not returning anything just printing!`). So, nothing is expected to be returned and as a result we have not captured any return value in `func(*args, **kwargs)`

```
@calculate_time_decorator
def myfunc():
    print('Not returning anything just printing!')
```

***Sources:***

https://www.learnpython.org/en/Decorators

https://hackernoon.com/decorators-in-python-8fd0dce93c08